# How to find unicode of a text smiley in android

Tags: android, unicode

I am having a string like Hello world :) ;) and I want to get the Unicode of these characters :) ;)

How can I find the Unicode of these characters.

Please post the code if anyone have idea here.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: are you trying to convert :) to  or are you asking for the unicode equivalent for :) and ;) ?

Comment: Yes, I want to convert :) to unicode, so that I can convert them in emoticons.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
private static String escapeNonAscii(String str) {

StringBuilder mStr = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
int cp = Character.codePointAt(str, i);
int charCount = Character.charCount(cp);
if (charCount > 1) {
  i += charCount - 1; // 2.
  if (i >= str.length()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("truncated unexpectedly");
  }
}

 if (cp < 128) {
   mStr .appendCodePoint(cp);
 } else {
   mStr .append(String.format("\\u%x", cp));
 }
}
return mStr.toString();
}
```

Comment: If I call this function by passing the string :) or ;) it returns me the same string. I am not able to find any unicode of these strings.

Answer (score 0):

One way to convert :) to  would be to create a HashMap and populate it with smiley codes. Then you just need to replace all occurences of the keys with their respective values. Example:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(":\\)", "\uD83D\uDE42");//don't forget to escape the parenthesis character in :)
map.put(":\\(", "\uD83D\uDE41");
map.put(":D", "\uD83D\uDE00");
...
String s = "Hello World :)";
Set<String> set = map.keySet();
for (String s1 : set) {
    s = s.replaceAll(s1, map.get(s1));
}
```

Here is a list of [Unicode emoticons](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm).

Comment: I do not want to store the smiley texts in a map, I want to check it dynamically and then change it in Unicode. How can I do that, please post the example code if anyone know how to do it.

Comment: You do realize that ':' and ')' are separate unicode characters and  is 1 unicode character? This is no different than replacing 'ab' with 'c'. Plus, you want to replace occurences of different characters, so you'll actually need a lookup table for that, or a very long if else chain. Of course you can try to look for some library that does it for you, but the library itself will use something similar to replace the characters.

Comment: Ok, I can try adding the text smileys in a hashmap by adding the text smiley and it's unicode in hashmap.
But how will I find the corresponding unicode for a text smiley.
For Ex:  I know that for this :) text smiley unicode is "\uD83D\uDE42" 
How would I find the corresponding Unicode for other text smileys.

Comment: Check the provided link, there you will find a list of emoticons. Click on the character code and scroll to the Encodings table - there you will find **C/C++/Java source code    "\uD83D\uDE06"**. Or you can paste the emoticon character directly to android studio and it will be converted automatically.

Comment: It is fine that we have a static table for all emoticons but can we handle it programmatically. Ex: By using some method can we find the Unicode of corresponding emoji icon of a text smiley.
If I type :) that function should return it's emoji icon's unicode `0x1f60a` Because I do not know the corresponding text smiley characters of lots of emoticons. 
Ex: I know that for smiley face  I have to type :) But I do not know that to make this emoticon  what should I type using text keyboard.
So I want  a method which can convert text smiley into unicode.
Thank you so much for all your help.